# SAML Assertion is being replayed in Internet Explorer 11 only

Tags: internet-explorer, saml, saml-2.0

We have an issue with SAML and IE 11 only.  All other browsers and versions of IE work with our SAML implementation.  Only IE 11 fails to log in.  When it fails we get the error "SAML Assertion is being replayed".  Also we see that the Remote IDP is POSTing the assertion twice in quick succession.  This is a .NET custom implementation.  Is there something IE 11 has changed that would cause this type of issue?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues with IE 11. Have you tried using Fiddler to capture the HTTP traffic to see if the SAML response HTTP Post is being sent twice somehow?

Comment: Is the Web Server HTTPS certificate at the SP trusted (no SSL handshake issues) or is the message being POST'd within a iFrame?

Comment: yes we use fiddler.  This is how we can see the two identical posts.  The issue is that it is being sent twice.  We are trying to determine why it is being sent twice in IE 11 and no other browser.

Comment: Our SSLs are good, and we are not posting in an iframe.  We are also looking into some of the set up configurations on the IDP side.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Is the SP issuing any redirects as a response to the POST? Or is it two consecutive POSTs? Have you disabled all browser plugins as well that might interfere?

Comment: As an experiment, disable Javascript in IE. You should be presented with a button to manually initiate posting of the SAML response. This would help rule out any issues with the Javascript that's used to automatically post the SAML response.